# How to preserve spaces when outputting a shell variable?

Tags: string, bash, whitespace, substitution

For string matching purposes I need to define a bash variable with leading spaces.
I need to define this starting from an integer, like:

```
jj=5
```

printf seems to me a good idea, so if I want to fill spaces up to 6 character:

```
jpat=`printf "  %6i"  $jj`
```

but unluckly when I am trying to recall the variable:

```
echo $jpat
```

the leading whitespaces are removed and I only get the `$jj` integer as it was.

Any solution to keep such spaces?

(This is equivalent to this: `v='  val'; echo $v$v`. Why aren't there leading and multiple spaces in output?)

Comment: Quote it: `echo "$jpat"`. This keeps the format.

Comment: oh, right, thanks ... so easy :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Use More Quotes!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) `echo "$jpat"` will do what you want.

There is another issue with what you're doing: Command substitutions will *remove* trailing newlines. It's not an issue in the `printf` command you're using, but for example assigning `jpat=$(printf "  %6i\n"  "$jj")` would give you exactly the same result as your command.